# Select com quantidade indefinidos de condições

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

É o seguinte, eu tenho um campo de pesquisa, e quero pesquisar em locais distintos do que está cadastrados, tipo assim: `tenis nike shox preto`.

Eu coloco na pesquisa: `tenis preto`. Se eu usar um descrição `like '%tenis preto%'` ele não me retornara nada.

Eu teria que colocar descrição `like '%tenis%' or descricao like '%preto%'`.

Até ai tudo bem, eu coloco no SQL lá duas condições, porem e se ele quiser pesquisar com 3 ou mais palavras, vai variar a quantidade de `where` que eu preciso usar, tem como fazer isso?

Estou usando:

- PHP
- PostgreSQL

Comment: Algumas soluções apresentadas utilizam queries dinâmicas. Sugiro que quem for utiliza-las pelo menos estude os prós e contras de utilizar esse tipo de técnica

Comment: Sugeriria inclusive ler o conceito de query dinâmica, pois olhando as respostas dadas, nenhuma delas aplica esse conceito quanto ao ponto de vista do _engine_ de SQL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Não é necessário montar strings, o que aliás é má prática. Basta passar os parâmetros na forma de array com qualquer das duas sintaxes:

```
select *
from t
where descricao ilike any ('{"%tenis%", "%nike%", "%shox%", "%preto%"}')

select *
from t
where descricao ilike any (array['%tenis%', '%nike%', '%shox%', '%preto%'])
```

`ilike` é insensível à caixa. A lógica acima é de `or`. Se for necessário fazer `and` troca-se o `any` por `all`

Comment: O papo de má prática eu estou desconsiderando, pq não tem o mínimo embasamento, mas de qq forma recebeu meu +1 por ser uma solução técnica adequada usando um recurso do SGBD.

Answer (score 4):

Uma possibilidade com um resultado mais completo é usar o PHP para dividir a sua pesquisa em palavras separadas, e gerar a clausula WHERE pra você:

```
<?php

   $pesquisa = 'carro verde amassado ';

   // Aqui você pode juntar vários campos no concat.
   $campo = 'CONCAT( title, " ", description, " ", author)';
   // Ou usar um só, mas nesse caso talvez compense um LIKE tradicional
   // $campo = 'title';

   $palavras = explode( ' ', $pesquisa ); // dividindo as palavras pelo espaço
   $palavras = $array_filter($palavras); // eliminando ítens vazios

   $where = '';
   $cola = 'WHERE ';

   foreach ($palavras as $palavra) {
      $palavra = trim($palavra); //Removendo espaços em branco
      $palavra = mysql_real_escape_string($palavra); // Aqui você sanitiza de acordo com o DB
      $where .= $cola.campo.' LIKE "%'.$palavra.'%" ';
      $cola = 'AND ';
   }

   echo htmlentities( $where );
?>
```

E o resultado será:

```
WHERE
   CONCAT( title, " ", description, " ", author) LIKE "%carro%" AND
   CONCAT( title, " ", description, " ", author) LIKE "%verde%" AND
   CONCAT( title, " ", description, " ", author) LIKE "%amassado%"
```

(quebras de linha adicionadas para facilitar a leitura)

Desta forma a pesquisa encontrará todos esses resultados:

```
O carro amassado era verde
A carroceria foi atingida por abacates verdes amassados
Verde e amassado carro
```

Note que apesar de algumas linhas não terem resultados exatos, é melhor ter coisas a mais do que o usuário não encontrar o que precisa. Tenha em mente, no entanto, que o preço que se paga pela complexidade é uma pesquisa mais lenta. `LIKE` e índices não trabalham bem juntos.

Comment: Uma solução simples mas que infelizmente usa queries dinâmicas que não são recomendadas. Se for utilizar esta solução sugiro pelo menos sanitizar o input e se puder parametrizar a query (possivelmente usando Stored Procedure)

Comment: Sanitização foi feita já, leia melhor a resposta `$palavra = mysql_real_escape_string($palavra);`. Stored procedure não tem o mínimo proveito num caso desses.

Comment: Tem todo proveito: Primeiro e mais importante barrar ataques de SQL Inject, segundo performance. Sugiro ler este artigo sobre como criar condições dinâmicas. http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html#casestudy

Comment: Não tem como usar um ataque de injeção, sendo que já está sanitizado. Li o artigo, principalmente no parágrafo que inicia a questão das condições dinâmicas de pesquisa, e ele não se aplica em nada ao nosso caso, tem certeza que leu direito? Inclusive, pelo jeito você não entendeu que condição dinâmica não é nada disso que eu fiz na resposta. Quando a query chega no engine SQL, ela está montada já. Para o _engine_, é uma query igual qualquer outra. Sugeriria começar pelo básico, e depois tentar se aprofundar nestes conceitos.

Comment: Discordo, no artigo tem técnicas ensinando como montar queries e quais são os pró e contra dessa abordagem além de outras idéias que podem ser exploradas como queries dinâmicas parametrizáveis. Sempre que você montar queries você está correndo o risco de SQL inject, sanitizar não é 100% seguro, existem técnicas para burlar a sanitização como mandar os códigos dos caracteres e corrigindo você: as queries chegam montadas à engine porém um SP já está compilada. Queries dinâmicas não paramétricas precisam ser recompiladas e não fazem bom uso de cache e estatísticas. Leia +

Answer (score 1):

Depende da complexidade da funcionalidade que você quer implementar e do tamanho da sua aplicação. Para uma aplicação pequena e simples você pode fixar até três campos, exigir que pelo menos o primeiro esteja preenchido e fazer três likes sendo que os likes dos campos não preenchidos seriam algo como `LIKE "%"`.

Agora se você precisa de mais complexidade e uma aplicação maior sugiro você implementar uma tabela de tags e uma tabela de relacionamento entre tags e registros que você quer retornar.

Ao fazer uma busca tipo google o array de strings é enviado para a função que vai procurar registros que estejam relacionados àquelas tags.

Com um pouco mais de complexidade você pode implementar ranks de tags; ignorar as tags com menor ranks caso elas façam com que não haja um retorno mínimo; ignorar flexões de género, número e verbais; automatizar a extração de tags dos registros; etc

Implementei algo assim uma vez mas para MS-SQL e .Net pois apesar do SGBD ter ferramentas nativas para esse tipo de `SELECT` a hospedagem não permitia ativa-las (a menos que o servidor fosse dedicado, o que era caro).

Answer (score 0):

Amigo. Existe uma solução simples para seu problema.

Estou utilizando o `MySql`, mas é de fácil alteração para seu caso.

Primeiramente, defina as colunas na qual você quer buscar o valor, imaginando que seja mais de uma.(Funciona para 1 ou N colunas).

```
/* Colunas da Tabela */
$aColumns = array (
        'ID',
        'PRODUTO',
        'DESCRICAO'
);
```

Em seguida monte o `WHERE`:

```
/* Filtros.. */     
$sWhere = "";
if ($_GET ['sSearch'] != "") {
    $sWhere = "WHERE (";
    for($i = 0; $i < count ( $aColumns ); $i ++) {
        $sWhere .= $aColumns [$i] . " LIKE '%" . strtoupper ( mysql_real_escape_string ( $_GET ['sSearch'] ) ) . "%' OR ";
    }
    $sWhere = substr_replace ( $sWhere, "", - 3 );
    $sWhere .= ')';
}
```

Porém continuará o problema em questão, para a busca, caso seja procurado: `Tenis Preto`, só irá retornar os valores que contenham o intervalo total.

Como solução, pode-se utilizar o [IMPLODE](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php) e o [EXPLODE](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php):

```
$busca  = "Tenis Nike Preto"; //Set GET ou POST..
$busca_explode =  explode(' ', $busca); //Desmonta String..
print_r($busca_explode) ; // Visualização como fica..
$busca_total = implode('%', $busca_explode); // Tenis%Nike%Preto
echo '<br>'.$busca_total;
```

Basta passar este valor para o `WHERE` acima em vez de buscar direto pelo `$_GET ['sSearch']`.