# SQL usando um Array de palavras

Tags: php, mysql, sql

É o seguinte tenho um campo de pesquisa em um formulário onde o usuário digita por exemplo uma cor ou produto e é retornado a ele uma lista de produtos com as características digitadas no formulário, o problema e o seguinte, quando passo o array na SQL me é retornado: **Notice:** Array to string conversion, entretanto vi aqui mesmo no pt.stack publicações onde se passavam arrays dentro da sql. A seguir o código PHP responsável pela criação do Array:

```
            $values = explode(' ',$values);
            $keywords = array();
            foreach($values as $value){
                $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
                $value = '%' . $value . '%;';
                $keywords[] = $value;
            }
            $query = "SELECT title, urlvideo FROM $colunm WHERE title ILIKE ANY ($keywords)";
            echo $query;
```

Link de Base: [Link do pt.stackoverflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37105/select-com-quantidade-indefinidos-de-condi%C3%A7%C3%B5es)

Seria possível fazer isto em PDO também?

Comment: Parece quem falta um `implode` e virgulas para formar a lista de palavras no `ANY()`

Comment: A rotina que eu especifiquei na resposta que eu dei nessa pergunta que você mencionou serve para MySQL sem problema (incluso PDO). E não se preocupe muito com os comentários de determinado usuário lá, pois não tem o mínimo fundamento técnico. Quanto ao mysql_real_escape_string, que provavelmente veio da resposta que mencionei, mude para a sanitização do PDO (supondo que tenha).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Aquela questão *[Select com quantidade indefinidos de condições](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37105/select-com-quantidade-indefinidos-de-condi%C3%A7%C3%B5es)* é sobre PostgreSQL e o seu código é sobre MySQL, portanto provavelmente não tem como funcionar.
2. `ILIKE` não é suportado pelo MySQL, você pode usar vários `LIKE`s ou `REGEXP` no MySQL para obter o mesmo efeito.
3. `ANY` no MySQL é diferente do PostgreSQL, enquanto no PostgreSQL você usar para consultar usando arrays, no MySQL você usa para consultar com sub-queries (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html)
4. PHP deve ser uma `string`, você deve usar `implode` para juntar a `array` em uma `string` com o formato de `array` para MySQL, desta maneira (*acaso você venha a usa PostgreSQL*):
5. Note para que o MySQL suporte consulta *case-insensitive* você deve usar os *collections* com o final `_ci`, por exemplo: `utf8_general_ci`

### PostgreSQL:

`'{"' . implode('", "', $keywords) . '"}'`

E remova o ponto e virgula nesta linha:

`$value = '%' . $value . '%;';` deixando assim `$value = '%' . $value . '%';`

> Uma dica: acredito que o correto seria você recuperar o valor, usando `as $k => $v`

### MySQL `LIKE` com `implode`:

Note que neste exemplo é necessário usar "apóstrofos": `$value = '\'%' . $value . '%\'';`

```
        foreach($values as $k => $v){
            $value = mysql_real_escape_string($v);
            $value = '\'%' . $value . '%\''; //Adicionado apóstrofos
            $keywords[] = $value;
        }
        $query = 'SELECT title, urlvideo FROM ' . $colunm . ' WHERE title LIKE ' . implode(' OR title LIKE ', $keywords);
```

Deve retornar algo como:

`SELECT title, urlvideo FROM table WHERE title LIKE '%A%' or title LIKE '%B%' or title LIKE '%C%'`

### MySQL `REGEXP`:

Note que usando `REGEXP` você deve remover os sinais `%` desta linha 
`$value = '%' . $value . '%';` deixando ela assim `$value = $value;`, pois estes sinais são necessários neste caso apenas com `LIKE`.

```
        foreach($values as $k => $v){
            $value = mysql_real_escape_string($v);
            $value = $value; //Removido %
            $keywords[] = $value;
        }
        $query = 'SELECT title, urlvideo FROM ' . $colunm . ' WHERE title REGEXP \'' . implode('|', $keywords) . '\'';
```

Deve retornar algo como:

`SELECT title, urlvideo FROM table WHERE title REGEXP 'A|B|C'`

### Usando PDO:

É possivel trabalhar arrays diretamente com `prepare`, conforme [esta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10722827/1518921).

> Note que é necessário passar os `%` no `execute`, pois se você usar no `prepare` assim:
>   `prepare('SELECT title, urlvideo FROM table WHERE title title LIKE \'%?%\'');` o servidor irá interpretar o código assim: `SELECT title, urlvideo FROM table WHERE title title LIKE '%'?'%'`, ou seja irá adicionar apóstrofos (AKA aspas simples) dentro da instrução `'%...%'`

Exemplo de uso:

```
$values = explode(' ', $values);

$keywords = array();
foreach($values as $k => $v){
    $keywords[] = '%' . $v . '%';
}

$db = new PDO(...);
$keys = 'title LIKE ' . str_repeat('? OR title LIKE ', count($keywords) - 1) . '?';
$sth = $db->prepare('SELECT title, urlvideo FROM ' . $colunm . ' WHERE ' . $keys);
$response = $sth->execute($keywords);

if ($response) {
    while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        var_dump($row);
    }
} else {
    echo 'Erro: ';
    var_dump($sth->errorInfo());
}
```

Documentação [PDOStatement::execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

### Usando PDO e REGEXP:

```
$values = explode(' ', $values);

$db = new PDO(...);
$keys = str_repeat('?|', count($values) - 1) . '?';
$sth = $db->prepare('SELECT title, urlvideo FROM ' . $colunm . ' WHERE title REGEXP \'' . $keys . '\'');
$sth->execute($values);
```

Comment: OK @GuilhermeNascimento funcionou 100%, uma curiosidade usando bindParam temos a opção de atribuir um PDO::PARAM_STR, PDO::PARAM_INT, isso tambem é possivel aqui?

Comment: @RicardoHenrique Acredito que só usando algo como `foreach ($params as $key => $val) {
    $sth->bindParam($key, $val);
}`